# Curved stairway re-do

Tags: router, circular-saw, sabre-saw

newbie here.  I'm about to tackle rebuilding the 180 degree curved, plywood/carpeted stairs in my home with solid 3/4" oak treads and painted hardboard risers.  My question has to do with cutting the arc into the outside edge of the treads - specifically which method to use - router, circular saw or sabre saw. This will be a cross-cut using a trammel and the cut edge will butt against the wall and will not be visible.  Eager to know your thoughts and the thoughts behinds them (like "he's insane"...).   Thanks!

---

By 180 degrees I mean if I'm standing on the first step and facing north, by the time I climb up the 14 steps, I'll be facing south.  Regardless, the question was the best method to cut a soft arc in oak using a trammel.

Comment: You really need to include some photos or a lot more detail.  "180 degree curved" does not describe your situation clearly enough to give any kind of meaningful advice.

Comment: Agree with @SaSSafraS1232 here, pictures very much needed here for proper input. But on cutting curves in general, you wouldn't use a circular saw normally! They are very much geared to cutting straight. Curves would tend to suggest jigsaws or sabre saws ([can be the same thing](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1423/what-is-the-difference-between-a-sabre-saw-and-a-jig-saw)) if not doing the cuts with a suitable handsaw. Final dressing or smoothing of the cut face can be left to the router.

Comment: If I had only one of the three tools that you mentioned, I would not hesitate to use it.  Having all three, I would use the one that I feel most comfortable using. Sabre saw is probably fastest (single cut does the job), router and circular saw will take multiple passes, but will leave cleaner edges. Router is not a go-to tool for me.  I love cutting outside curves with a circular saw.